# How to filter only out going packets using wireshark

Tags: wireshark

How to filer only outgoing packets with respect to some port number?

Example IP is `A.B.C.D`  and port is **443**. Then have to filter only outgoing packets from port 443, so how can I do?

Comment: I genuinely don't understand why you have tagged this under C#, VB.NET, and Perl. Please refrain from tag spam in future and select appropriate tags (i.e. wireshark).

Comment: This also doesn't sound like a Wireshark question.  It actually sounds like a Firewall question.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose your IP address is A.B.C.D and you are going to filter out outgoing TCP packets which their source port is 443; In this case you can simply use the following filter:

ip.src == A.B.C.D && tcp.srcport==443

Comment: Understood wxShayan.